# Does equation $a^b+b^c+c^a=d^e$ have solutions in $\mathbb {N}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does equation $a^b+b^c+c^a=d^e$ has solution s in $\mathbb {N}$

My trial: If there is no restriction for equality of a, b, c , d and e then for these numbers all $\leq 10$ we have 36 set of solutions such as (2, 2, 4, 6,2), (1, 2, 1, 2, 2).I found these by a simple Python program.I have two questions:

1- How one calculates the number of sets of solutions for all numbers in equation $\leq n$, for example $n=10$?

2- Has this equation solutions in $\mathbb{N}$ when $a\neq b$,$b\neq c$, $c\neq d$, $d\neq e$, $e\neq a$ when $a, b, c, d, e> 1$?

Comment: Parity of $d$ comes down to combined parity of $a,b,c$

Comment: Pick arbitrary $a,b,c$, and then let $e=1, d = a^b+b^c+c^a$. The same idea can be used to find all possible solutions.

Comment: The relation $\ne$ is not transitive. Each of $a,b,c,d,$ and $e$ should be unequal to all the other ones, not just the one immediately following it. One should also have $a \ne c, a \ne d, a \ne e, b \ne d, b \ne e,$ and $c \ne e$.

Comment: $6^3+3^2+2^6=17^2$ where $c=e$ holds.

Comment: I think LCM might help, as although it doesn't produce more easily, it does produce equations with nearly all different. Like $24^3+24^2+4^6=136^2$ which we might learn if we can shape shift to work or not.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ have to be distinct and greater than $1$ , then upto $a,b,c=400$ , the only perfect power upto permutation is the one mentioned by mathlove.

Comment: And we have to contend with $a^b+b^c\equiv d^e\pmod c$ and the like.